# how to swap the first digit(if not largest among the digits) with largest digit in an integer

Tags: java, algorithm

EDIT : I am unable to keep track of the second largest digit in an integer and swap that with the first digit in the integer to make the integer the largest... (For Example if i have my input as `31548` i am unable to swap 3 with 8 as my code swaps 3 with 5 and gives `51348` and again it runs through the rest and then swaps with 8 and gives `81345` which i don't want...)  and For sequences of digits with the highest digit already in the leftmost position like if my input is 877115755 the output should ignore the first three digits 877 and consider the smaller fourth digit 1 and swap the next occurence of 7 and output 877715155.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int value = 621007349;

    String number = String.valueOf(value);

    int[] arr = new int[number.length()];

    int length = (int) (Math.log10(value) + 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Char at " + number.charAt(i));
        arr[i] = number.charAt(i) - '0';
    }

    int var = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        int temp = arr[i];
        for (int j = i; j < arr.length-1; j++) {
            if (j < arr.length - 1) {
                if (arr[j + 1] > temp) {
                    if (var < arr[j + 1]) {
                        var = arr[j + 1];
                        System.out.println("Larg Val " + arr[j+1]);
                        System.out.println("First no "+arr[i]);

                        int tmp = arr[j+1];
                        arr[j+1] = arr[i];
                        arr[i] = tmp;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
        System.out.println("Values in arry are " + arr[j]);
    }
}
```

Input is `621007349` and Output should be `921007346`

Please help me on where did i go wrong...

Comment: Why not use a debugger and step through your code to find out where exactly it's going wrong?

Comment: You have words describing the goal to achieve. Make a textual description of how to achieve it. Comment your code: how would a reader know if the difficulty is in devising a procedure (to avoid "algorithm") or in coding it? In a comment to _Ali Amiri_'s answer, you refined the requirements for sequences of digits with the highest digit already in the leftmost position: please update the question. As an alternative to manipulating digits, try manipulating the numerical value to achieve the same effect between decimal representations before& after. (Neither better nor easier: one more exercise.)

Comment: Sure greybeard i'll do that...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**EDIT :** Add a while loop to for replacing first possible number with the maximum number after that:

I remove the inner loop and change conditions a little(also remove swap from inside the loop to after loop) and now [your code](http://ideone.com/GUpy7x) works fine:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    int value = 877115755;

    String number = String.valueOf(value);

    int[] arr = new int[number.length()];

    int length = (int) (Math.log10(value) + 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        arr[i] = number.charAt(i) - '0';
    }
    int var = arr[0];
    int index = 0;
    int startIndex = 0;
    boolean changed = false;

    while(startIndex<arr.length-1){
        var = arr[startIndex];
        for (int i = startIndex+1; i < arr.length; i++) {
            int temp = arr[i];
            if (temp > var) {
                var = temp;
                index = i;
                changed = true;
                System.out.println("Larg Val "+arr[i]);
            }
        }
        if(changed)
            break;
        startIndex++;
    }

    //this is the swap part
    int tmp = arr[index];
    arr[index] = arr[startIndex];
    arr[startIndex] = tmp;  

    for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
        System.out.println("Values in arry are " + arr[j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I second you with the above code... However if my input is 877115755 the output should be 877715155 for which the above code is just printing the same input..

Comment: @inevitableKris I changed my code as you wanted, now check it and tell me if there is any thing that you dont understand ;)

Comment: Thanks Ali Amiri this works... but for if my input is 10 it is giving 01 it dosen't matter i'll handle that...

Comment: @inevitableKris if it is your answer please mark it as an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try, getting first the `max` position and then just do a simple swap:

```
public static int get_max(int[] arr){
  int max_pos = 0;
  int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
  for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if ( arr[i] > max) {
      max = arr[i];
      max_pos = i;
    }
  }
  return max_pos;
}

public static void swap(int[] arr, int st, int dt) {
  int temp = arr[st];
  arr[st] = arr[dt];
  arr[dt] = temp;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int value = 621007349;

    String number = String.valueOf(value);

    int[] arr = new int[number.length()];

    int length = (int) (Math.log10(value) + 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Char at " + number.charAt(i));
        arr[i] = number.charAt(i) - '0';
    }

    int pos_max = get_max(arr);
    swap(arr, 0, pos_max);

    for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
        System.out.println("Values in arry are " + arr[j]);
    }
}
```

---

**Updated**: If you want to replace the digits with max in non-increasing order:

```
public static int get_max(int[] arr, int stPosition){
  int max_pos = 0;
  int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
  for (int i = stPosition; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if ( arr[i] > max) {
      max = arr[i];
      max_pos = i;
    }
  }
  return max_pos;
}
// swap is same

// replace get_max and swap with
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  int pos_max = get_max(arr, i); // gets max from i to arr.length
  if (pos_max == i)
    continue;
  swap(arr, i, pos_max);
}
```

Comment: This is not working for this input 820715607... it is giving 720815607 which is not largest integer. Correct me if i am wrong... My point is if there is a largest digit in the first position the code should check for the second digit if it is smallest then it should swap and so on...

Comment: you want to do the swap recursively... Like 820715607 --> 870215607
Also, corrected the issue with max calculation, should be fine now if you want just replacement of the first digit (with the highest digit (can be itself also))